# Ayuda para mover un elemento con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

quiero mover un elemento div que esta en un TD de una tabla a otro TD de la misma fila, y no logro hacerlo sin errores, asi que lo consulto a ver si puede alguien ayudarme:

```
<table>

<thead>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
<th>D</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td> <div class="ABC"></div> <div class="Mover"><a href="/lolo/1"></a></div></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="/lola/1"></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <div class="ABC"></div> <div class="Mover"><a href="/lolo/2"></a></div></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="/lola/2"></a></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Estoy intentando con este codigo:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[href^="/lola/"]'), function(elem) {

    var slw = elem.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.Mover');
    //se encuentran los elementos con la clase "Mover" dentro de la misma FILA.
    var slwdata = document.createElement('div');
    slwdata.innerHTML = slw.outerHTML;
    elem.parentNode.appendChild(slwdata);
});
```

Por ultimo trato de agregarlo al TD actual.
Primero recibía un error diciendo que no era  un nodo entonces lo estoy intentando hacer creando antes un elemento.

En fin deberia quedar el ultimo TD de cada FILA así:

```
<td>
<a href="/lola/2"></a>
<div class="Mover"><a href="/lolo/2"></a></div>
</td>

Eliminando el DIV con CLASE Mover de laa anteriores TD..
```

Si al codigo anterior lo ejecuto 2 veces en la consola funciona (no borra el DIV DEL td ANTERIOR pero eso no es un problema porque puedo borrarlo, pero la primera vez da el error:
VM12047:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null
    at :5:29
    at NodeList.forEach ()
    at :1:12

Comment: A = Div.html() obtienes el html de ese div y con td.html(A) lo agregas

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez esa es una función jQuery, y OP está usando JS puro

Comment: Por eso es un comentario ;)

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro si es lo que querías, pero le hice un par de modificaciones a tu js (aparte de agregar algo de info extra al html para saber si es que se mostraban los links) y quedó algo como esto. Dime si es lo que necesitabas:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('[href^="/lola/"]')
links.forEach(function(elem) {

    var slw = elem.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.Mover');
    //se encuentran los elementos con la clase "Mover" dentro de la misma FILA.
    var slwdata = document.createElement('div');
    slwdata.innerHTML = slw.outerHTML;
    elem.parentNode.appendChild(slwdata);
});
```

```html
<table>

  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="ABC">link:</div>
        <div class="Mover"><a href="/lolo/1">1</a></div>
      </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><a href="/lola/1">1</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="ABC">link:</div>
        <div class="Mover"><a href="/lolo/2">2</a></div>
      </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td><a href="/lola/2">2</a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ojo, que el código que pusiste, más que mover lo que hace es copiar.

Comment: Hola @Alter Lagos gracias por tu respuesta! mira lo que quiero es mover el elementto, o si no se puede mover copiarlo primero y agregarlo al ultimo TD y luego borrarlo del TD en el que el DIV estaba anteriormente.   Sé que con JQuery esta tarea es algo sencilla pero quiero hacerlo sin JQuery.  Lo que quiero es mover el <div class="Mover"><a href="/lolo/1"></a></div> al ultimo TD. Voy a probar el codigo gracias.

Comment: Te comento el codigo funciona y copia el elemento con clase Mover de cada fila al ultimo TD PERO SOLO FUNCIONA SI LO EJECUTO 2 VECES Y ESTO ES LO QUE NO ENTIENDO! En definitiva debe haber otra forma de mover ese DIV y agregarlo al ultimo TD.

Answer (score 1):

Con tu código seria algo como:

```js
document.getElementById("mover").addEventListener("click",() => {

  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('[href^="/lola/"]')
  divs.forEach((e) => {
    var slw = e.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.Mover');
    var slwdata = document.createElement('div');
    slwdata.innerHTML = slw.outerHTML;
    e.parentNode.appendChild(slwdata);
    slw.remove();
  });

});
```

```css
.ABC{
  border:1px solid red;
}

.Mover{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <div class="ABC">DIV ABC</div>
        <div class="Mover">
          <a href="/lolo/1">DIV Mover</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/lola/1"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <div class="ABC">DIV ABC</div> 
        <div class="Mover">
          <a href="/lolo/2">DIV Mover</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/lola/2"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="center">
        <button id="mover">Mover DIVs</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Simplemente recorro cada link y seteo su HTML con **innerHTML**, el valor seteado del html sera **slw.outerHTML** que es el html del div que quiere mover.